# can i append a range in python

Tags: python, pygame

hi I was wondering if there is a possible way to append a range with another value. this is for a generator i am making in pygame, i want it to generate another random value if that place on the grid is taken

```
for i in range(60):
    RandomRow = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
    RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)

    if not Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow]:
        TempTile = MapTile('walls', RandomColumn, RandomRow)
        Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow].append(TempTile)
    else:
        range.append(1)
```

Comment: You would need to turn the range into a list first. A range is basically just a simple object than holds three numbers and calculates elements as needed.

Comment: Changing the iterator you're looping over in a for-loop is always a bad idea. Try using a while loop.

Comment: @debsim, I value your point. Can you explain why it would be a bad idea? The while loop would function exactly the same, so why choose it over for? I'd really like to know.

Comment: @FaithlessS I can't edit my previous comment anymore but "is usually considered bad practice" would be more correct than "is always a bad idea". I don't remember the exact reason and after a quick search I could find a very clear answer but I suppose it is related to readability. Usually with a for loop it's clear in advance how many times it will loop and over wich objects. With a for loop it's more like "keep going until this condition is satisfied" so you don't really know how long it will take.

Comment: But as some answers here point out, you CAN achieve what you want with a for loop (eg. with a list that gets appended) but if you have the possibility I think it's considered "better" to do it with a while loop because that's why it exists.

Comment: @MihirJoshi It's bad to change an iterator you're iterating over because it's error prone and I think it's undefined behaviour (i.e. there's no guarantee that'll be correct) as the iterator is expecting the sequence to be unmodified. They explicitly states in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html) that _"If you need to modify the sequence you are iterating over while inside the loop (for example to duplicate selected items), it is recommended that you first make a copy."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the range object and in general, it is considered bad practice to change the iterator that you're looping over in a for loop.

I'd suggest changing the for loop in a while loop, something like this:

```
end = 60
i = 0
for while i < end:
    RandomRow = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
    RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)

    if not Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow]:
        TempTile = MapTile('walls', RandomColumn, RandomRow)
        Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow].append(TempTile)
    else:
        end += 1 
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop variable to a list. Append to the list according to your usage.
e.g.:

```
range_list = [1,2,3]
for i in range_list:
    if *some condition*:
        //some code
    else:
       range_list.append(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you wish to do is to extend the for loop than no, its not possible. Once `range(n)` gets evaluated, you cannot alter it during the iteration.

if you run following code:

```
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    n += 1
```

This loop will still iterate 10 times, but `n` will be updated to 20.

I suggest changing `for` loop into `while` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < 60:
    RandomRow = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
    RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)

    if not Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow]:
        TempTile = MapTile('walls', RandomColumn, RandomRow)
        Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow].append(TempTile)
    else:
        i += 1
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems confusing to directly append values to a list while looping through it. Maybe you can use while loop together with a queue.Queue().

```
from queue import Queue
q = Queue()
for i in range(...):
    q.put(i)
while not q.empty():
    i = q.get()
    ... # process code
    if ...:
        q.put(...) # new elements to process.
```

Using a Queue, you have more freedom, instead of just processing consecutive integers.